# Why is the transition effect working only on one property?

Tags: html, css, css-transitions, css-transforms

```css
img {
  width: 40%;
  height: 30%;
  padding: 3%;
  transition: all 2s;
}
img:hover {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
  -webkit-transform: scaleX(2);
  -webkit-transition: all 1s;
}
```

```html
<img src="http://www.jqueryscript.net/images/Simplest-Responsive-jQuery-Image-Lightbox-Plugin-simple-lightbox.jpg">
```

Here, the transition property is defined for all properties. However, when the mouse is hovered over the image, only the second transform property (the one defining scaleX() function) is changed. The first transform property remains unchanged. Why is the first one not changing? How can I change both of them at the same time?

Comment: You need to write it on a single line: `-webkit-transform: rotate(360deg), scaleX(2);`

Comment: @n00dl3 I tried it but it caused even that one property to stop changing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
img {
  width: 40%;
  height: 30%;
  padding: 3%;
  transition: all 2s;
}
img:hover {
 -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg) scaleX(2);
 }
```

FIDDLE : https://jsfiddle.net/c6z4wy5x/

Comment: Don't we use comma to separate different values?

Comment: Is there some priority mechanism in CSS? Or does it just change the property preceding the transition property?